Is there a name for when multiple lines on a line graph follow a similar pattern?
I have a graph generated from crime statistics in 2022, and noticed that most of the time (except for Derbyshire in August) the lines all go up and down in the same months.
Is there a specific word that can be used to describe this relationship between the lines?


Approximately proportional

"Correlated" works.

"...have a nearly constant offset at all times..."

In econometrics this is often called "parallel trends" or "common trends". It is a vital assumption of the DID (difference-in-differences) method. (See https://theeffectbook.net/ch-DifferenceinDifference.html or Chapter 5.2 in Mostly Harmless Econometrics by Angrist & Pischke for more about DID)
